# Where do you configure what your React app server is sending back?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I have a front-end React app and a back-end Express app running on two different Heroku dynos. As far as I am aware, the front-end server has no knowledge of my Express app except when I specifically send queries to that API. Rather, my React app is somehow being served based on default settings, probably provided by create-react-app.

However, I am running into [this issue](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-render-after-refreshing) currently with my React Router routes, and the solution they provide is to add this code to the server:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

Well sure, that code is already present in my Express app, but we've already established that's not what's serving my React app. So where do I add the same (or similar) code to ensure that I am catching all possible routes and sending them to "index.html"?

UPDATE:
From additional reading I've done, it looks like the Webpack way of routing back to index.html is by setting `historyApiFallback` to true in webpack.config.js. However, I am not looking to eject CRA, as I think that will cause more long-term problems than it solves. In my node_modules/react-scripts/config folder, in the webpackDevServer.config.js file, this already exists:

```
historyApiFallback: {
      // Paths with dots should still use the history fallback.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/387.
      disableDotRule: true,
    }
```

Unless I'm misreading [this doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback), it seems as though that is equivalent to saying historyApiFallback = true. So shouldn't this already be working?

The other thing I found is that most people only encounter problems with this behavior during development because the hot reloading feature is only turned on in development. However, my understanding is when I deploy to Heroku, it builds a production version of my app automatically. But the automatic redirect from "/signup" to "/" is happening there as well. If the issue isn't solved by historyApiFallback, what could it be?

Routing file:

```
<Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/home" component={LandingPage} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" render={props => (
          <AuthPage authType="signup" {...props} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/login" render={props => (
          <AuthPage authType="login" {...props} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Are you using webpack to bundle React? If so, that is where it is configured, the `output` in your `webpack.config.js`.

Comment: I'm using create-react-app which uses Webpack by default. I shouldn't need to eject to configure this, right? I am noticing I have a number of webpack.config.js files in different places in my node_modules tree. The one that seems the most likely is node_modules > webpack-dev-server > client > webpack.config.js but this doesn't have any output options

Comment: I do not recommend changing anything in node_mofiles.

Comment: You might want to check out this article recommended in CRA docs: https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/

Comment: It seems strange to me that I would need to go through kind of a hacky workaround to customize CRA when I would imagine 99% of all React/React Router users would want to be able to type www.mydomain.com/signup and not have it redirect to www.mydomain.com/

Comment: Based on your update, this may have something to do with how your routes are set up and not necessarily with the deployment. It's possible that your router is catching the `/` before `signup` and rendering the `/` route instead. I think I had an issue at one point where I had to use `exact` on only the route with `/`.

Comment: I had that thought at first too, but I already have the `exact` keyword in use. See new update above @seanulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be far more simple and frustrating than any of the above answers. It turns out I had a  component at a higher level than my  component, which ran a hook that evaluated whether the user was authenticated and displayed a different NavBar in each scenario. Somehow this must have thrown off the lower-level routes and caused the redirect. When I moved the NavBar into the Routing file, things started working.

New code for Routing.js:

```
export const Routing = () => {
  const { location } = useReactRouter();

  const showSiteNav = () => {
    console.log(location);
    if (location.pathname === "/") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
  return (
    <>
      {showSiteNav() ? <SiteNav /> : null}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/home" component={LandingPage} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" render={props => (
          <AuthPage authType="signup" {...props} />
        )} />
        <Route path="/login" render={props => (
          <AuthPage authType="login" {...props} />
        )} />
      </Switch>
    </>
      )
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with some of my routes not rendering after deployment a little while ago. You might try adding the `basename` prop to `BrowserRouter` if that's what you are using:

```
<BrowserRouter basename='/'>
```

Alternatively, you might try adding the `base` tag to the `<head>` of your `index.html` file in your public folder:

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href='/'>
  ...
</head>
```

Then re-deploy and hopefully that will work. Note: While this might work, I believe it may be deprecated so, keep that in mind. In development, you can also use a `proxy` in you `package.json` just above the closing bracket.

```
"homepage": "./",
"proxy": "Your local host server"
```

Comment: None of these options seem to have worked. When I change my / to /signup it still redirects me to /.